# Which path should we choose to minimize the risk of being late?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

To get to work, a person has the choice between two paths A and B. The journey time (in minutes) follows a normal distribution of mean 55 and standard deviation 10 for path A and of mean 60 and of standard deviation 4 for path B.

Which path should we choose to minimize the risk of being late if we have 65 minutes?

1. Path A.
2. Path B.
3. Neither path A and B minimizes the risk of being late.

I have no clue how to do that? Do I have to use the MSE to find the best path?

Comment: Compute the probability of being late given path A and the probability of being late given path B. That should let you pick the best option.

Comment: Just figure out how many standard deviations $65$ is from the mean for each path, and choose the smaller one.

Comment: Making any progress, Doe?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, your answer was perfect! Thanks!

Comment: You could write it up, Doe, and post it as an answer.